# Multivariate mean value theorem in statistics context

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, statistics, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to understand the proof of the following theorem. As first step, he uses the mean value theorem for a multivariate function. After research online, it seems that this theorem does not generalize to such functions. Could anyone guide me to what the author really says? Thanks,the theorem is below.

[image]